# Getting 400: Bad Request while calling JSON POST REST Service from weblogic server

Tags: java, json, rest, weblogic-10.x

I have writtten one standalone client to call a Json REST Service POST method.

I am able to get response succesfully when I run it standalone but I am getting 
400 Bad Request error when I deploy it on weblogic server.

I am using JDK 1.5 and weblogic 10.3.0.

Below is the code :

```
String[] scope = { "openid", "profile", "email", "phone", "legacy" };
AuthTokenRequest authTokenRequest = new AuthTokenRequest();
authTokenRequest.setCode("685791bb-e39b-40a8-88f4-73a5fb7c01a");
authTokenRequest.setGrant_type("authorization_code");
URL url = new URL("https://api.ref.o2.co.uk/auth/v1/token");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
String input = "{\"code\":\"c88ae7e4-a2d4-4cc0-
aaeb16ca8a1467\",\"grant_type\":\"authorization_code\"}";
conn.getOutputStream().write(input.getBytes());
conn.getOutputStream().flush();
conn.getOutputStream().close();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn
.getInputStream())));

String output;System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");while      
((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(output);
}
conn.disconnect();
```

Comment: Are you sure the path you want to request to is accurate?

Comment: I notice you have a couple of strings that look like UUIDs at first glance but don't quite have the right number of characters. Are you sure those are correct?